# Storage of data for a form, you should be able to go back one step. When you close your browser (or refresh) the data should be gone

Tags: javascript, storage

There were are three steps on three pages, hou click next and you get to step 2. But if you should go back one step so you can change step 1. But if you refresh or close the browser the data should be gone. 
I was thinking on json. localstorage? But does this clear in case of refreshing or closing your browser? And how to use this correctly? Could you give me an working example?

Comment: `localstorage` yes. `clear in case of refreshing or closing` no. `how to use this correctly` find a tutorial.

Comment: You got the tricky bits figured out, time to read the [almighty SessionStorage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). They don't bite. You're looking for `SessionStorage`, not `LocalStorage`.